# Changing parts of a string

Tags: php

I am making a command conversion type system and here is what I am using for example if a string is:

```
if (strcmp(cmdtext, "/COMMAND", true) == 0)
```

I want to replace that however keep the string COMMAND in a variable then insert it into this string:

```
CMD:COMMAND(playerid, params[])
```

How would I go about doing this in PHP I have tried using a mixture of str_replace() and sscanf()

If the string is something like

```
if (strcmp(cmdtext, "/COMMAND", true) == 0)
    {
        Functions
        return 1;
    }
```

The brackets and everything in it will be a constant and the COMMAND will be a variable

Comment: you question is not clear. I am not sure which piece is constant and which is a variable

Comment: Unless `cmdtext` is a constant you should be getting errors now.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand, The bottom piece of code is an input inside a textarea, in PHP I want to change the code at the top into the 2nd piece of code but leave everything within the brackets.

Comment: Maybe regular expression can help you.

Comment: Can you show what the origional string is and what you want it to look like after?

Answer (score 0):

I would use some regular expressions in this case.

I assume that all commands are known.

```
$known_commands = "START|STOP|QUIT";
$out=preg_replace("#/($known_commands)#i", 'CMD:\1(playerid, params[])', '/START');
//$out contains string(29) "CMD:START(playerid, params[])"
```